# Python:Bindear 2 funciones a una misma tecla tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy tratando de hacer que al presionar sobre el boton Colores y elegir un color, al mantener presionado click sobre el widget canvas llame a la funcion draw, pero al presionar el boton borrar, al hacer la misma accion llame a la funcion delete, no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. ¿alguien tiene alguna idea?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.colorchooser import *

class Paint(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root = None):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Paint")
        self.root.geometry("+250+10")
        self.opcion = None

        self.root.bind("<B1-Motion>",self.draw)
        self.root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.reset_line)

        self.root.bind("<B3-Motion>",self.delete)
        self.root.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>",self.reset_line)


        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.Opciones = tk.Frame(self.root,bg="skyblue",width=800,height=60)
        self.Opciones.pack(side=tk.TOP,expand=True,fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.Opciones.pack_propagate(0)

        self.hoja = tk.Canvas(self.root,bg = "white",width = 800,height = 600)
        self.hoja.pack(expand=True,fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.Button = ttk.Style()
        self.Button.configure("Button.TButton",selectforeground = "white",fg="black",bg="skyblue",font=("Arial",12),height=1)

        self.Colores = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Colores",width=7,takefocus=0)
        self.Colores.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.E)

        self.Fondo = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Fondo",width=7,takefocus=0)
        self.Fondo.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.E)

        self.Scale = ttk.Style()
        self.Scale.configure("Scale.Horizontal.TScale",background="skyblue")

        self.Tamaño = ttk.Scale(self.Opciones,style="Scale.Horizontal.TScale",length=300)
        self.Tamaño.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.Borrar = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Borrar",width=7,takefocus=0)
        self.Borrar.place(relx=0.8,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.W)

        self.Copiar = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Copiar",width=7,takefocus=0)
        self.Copiar.place(relx=0.9,rely=0.5,anchor=tk.W)

    def draw(self,event):
        pass
    def delete(self,event):
        pass
    def reset_line(self,event):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = Paint(root = root)
    App.mainloop()
```

No pongo las funciones completas porque sino creo que no me permitiria realizar la pregunta

Comment: Actualmente el botón izquierdo llama a draw y el derecho a delete, ¿la idea sería que el boton izquierdo llame a ambas dependiendo de si se pulsó Colores o Borrar en último lugar?

Comment: si, esa seria la idea, que si se pulsa colores llame a draw o si se pulsa borrar llame a delete

Comment: He creado una respuesta que creo que responde a lo que buscas, si no se ajusta a lo deseado comenta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se quiere que un mismo evento esté asociado a más de una callback, ejecutando  una u otra o varias en función de alguna condición o condiciones establecidas lo más simple es crear una callback  que actúe de wrapper y que se encargue de llamar a la función final, por ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.colorchooser import *


class Paint(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Paint")
        self.root.geometry("+250+10")
        self.opcion = None
        self.b1_motion_action = lambda: None

        self.root.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_b1_motion)
        self.root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.reset_line)

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.opciones = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="skyblue", width=800, height=60)
        self.opciones.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.opciones.pack_propagate(0)

        self.hoja = tk.Canvas(self.root, bg="white", width=800, height=600)
        self.hoja.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.button = ttk.Style()
        self.button.configure(
            "Button.TButton", selectforeground="white", fg="black",
            bg="skyblue", font=("Arial", 12), height=1
            )

        self.colores = ttk.Button(
            self.opciones, style="Button.TButton",
            text="Colores", width=7, takefocus=0,
            command=lambda: self.change_action(self.draw)
            )
        self.colores.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.E)

        self.fondo = ttk.Button(
            self.opciones, style="Button.TButton",
            text="Fondo", width=7, takefocus=0,
            )
        self.fondo.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.E)

        self.scale = ttk.Style()
        self.scale.configure("Scale.Horizontal.TScale", background="skyblue")

        self.tamaño = ttk.Scale(
            self.opciones, style="Scale.Horizontal.TScale", length=300
            )
        self.tamaño.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.borrar = ttk.Button(
            self.opciones, style="Button.TButton",
            text="Borrar", width=7, takefocus=0,
            command=lambda: self.change_action(self.delete)
            )
        self.borrar.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.W)

        self.copiar = ttk.Button(
            self.opciones, style="Button.TButton",
            text="Copiar", width=7, takefocus=0
            )
        self.copiar.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.W)

    def draw(self, event=None):
        print("Dibujando.....")

    def delete(self, event=None):
        print("Borrando......")

    def reset_line(self, event=None):
        pass

    def change_action(self, action=lambda: None):
        self.b1_motion_action = action

    def on_b1_motion(self, event=None):
        self.b1_motion_action()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Paint(root=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Básicamente la callback `on_b1_motion` se encarga solamente de ejecutar el callable asociado al atributo `b1_motion_action`, los botones de dibujar y borrar (u otros que existieran) simplemente se dedican a reasignar un nuevo callable a `b1_motion_action`.

Comment: Muchas gracias ,esto era lo que necesitaba

Comment: Disculpa, nose si aqui se puede realizar una pregunta adicional pero ¿Cual es el motivo de igualar event a None y tambien el parametro action?

Comment: Lo de igualar a `None` es una costumbre más que nada en realidad XD, esto es un parámetro por defecto haciendo el parámetro opcional, de forma que podemos llamar a la función/método mediante `self.delete()` o mediante vself.delete(<un evento>)`. La utilidad es que hay casos en los que hay que aceptar el evento aunque no se use (enlaces con `bind` por ejemplo) y casos en los que no se pasa evento alguno (comandos de botones por ejemplo), por lo que la función puede ser usada universalmente en ambos casos como callback.

Comment: En cuanto a lo de `action`, en este caso `action` debe ser cualquier callable que será ejecutado cuando se haga click y se mueva el cursor. Le asigno un valor por defecto de `lambda: None` porque esto permite "resetear" la acción, es decir, si un botón invoca a `command=lambda: self.change_action()` o `command=self.change_action` o simplemente se llama al método desde cualquier lado con `self.self.change_action()` automáticamente `self.b1_motion_action` pasa a estar asociado a una función que retorna `None` y al hacer click y arrastrar sencillamente no se hará nada.

Comment: También se puede usar `lambda: 'break'` para los casos en los que se quiera también detener la propagación del evento.